# In thermodynamics what is a constant mass process called?

Tags: thermodynamics, mass, conventions, definition, ideal-gas

In thermodynamic processes you'll see defined conditions like *isochoric* for constant volume and *isothermal* for constant temperature, as examples.

In a general thermodynamic process you may have a flux of mass across the control volume, but in many cases the mass is fixed. So is there a definition or convention for naming a process where the mass is assumed to be constant?

iso -?

I'm specifically interested in thermodynamics applied to gases.

EDIT: I did a fairly thorough search on Google; probably defined in older textbooks.

Comment: While this may concern the english language SE more than this SE, that's a really interesting question, since "isobaric" means "of equal weight" in greek, but that one is kinda taken...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simply a **[closed system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_system#In_thermodynamics)**

> In thermodynamics, a closed system can exchange energy (as heat or work) but not matter, with its surroundings. An isolated system cannot exchange any heat, work, or matter with the surroundings, while an open system can exchange energy and matter.

Comment: Doh! Of course. The iso's had me off track. Thanks!